# Pass data from PHP to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I'm trying to make a website with php, mysql & `fullcalendar` jquery plugin where I want to show some datas of corresponding date from mysql table in the calendar but nothing is showing. Here is my js codes,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2015-04-12',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
        <?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
            {
                title: '<?php $row[1] ?>',  //'This is today!',
                start: '<?php $row[0] ?>'   //'2015-04-12'
            },
        <?php } ?>
            {
                title: 'It was yesterday!',
                start: '2015-04-11'
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Is there something wrong in my code? How can I fetch data and pass it to jquery? Need this help badly! Tnx.

Comment: you use data in json form convert the result of mysql_fetch_array($result) into json and used it

Comment: Besides the missing `echo` or `<?=`, It might have to do with the format of your dates. Is your field a `dateTime`? You need to make sure that your `start` field has a format like `YYYY-MM-DD` (without time) or `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` (with time).

Answer (score 0):

Add an "echo" before $row[x]. You need to do:
echo $row[1]; inside the php tags

Comment: Still not working. Only yesterday event showing since it was manually added.

Comment: What is the code your browser or firebug shows? Are you sure that the sql is returning any value?

Comment: php tags inside jquery are not showing in the browser console.

Comment: They never will since they are parsed before page is sent to browser.
Try var_dump'ing the row and see if it is not empty.

Comment: php tags won't appear at the browser console since php is executed in server side. What the browser console should show is the value for the keys title and start (the values returned from sql). If instead of this, there is a blank space, probably you have a php error (look in error_log file) or your sql query (that I supoose you have before the code you posted) isn't returning anything